# How to loop round Layer and stop on frame 1?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Ive seen gotoAndPlay and gotoAndStop but is there like a gotoAndLoop till frame 1 or something? Trying to do this all outside frames (code)

Comment: put gotoAndStop(1) on last frame

Comment: or if you have only 2 frames:) add prevFrame(); in the second frame - it was faster than gotoAndPlay(1);